# Using promises with backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to do something which is probably not able to be done, but essentially I am trying to gather data and then pass it all to a view, but I think the way promises work this is impossible.

So what I have is:

```
  create: function() {
    $('#blog-manage').empty();
    var options = {reset: true};
    var getTags = new AisisWriter.Collections.Tags({per: 9999});

    getTags.fetch(options).then(function(data){
      this.tags = data.tags //=> this.tags is a class level variable. data.tags = array of 5 objects.
    }, this);

    console.log(this.tags) //=> null
    var createPost = new AisisWriter.Views.CreatePost({tags: this.tags });
    createPost.render();
  },
```

I cannot figure out why in the promise the data.tags can be assigned to this.tags but out side of that `this.tags` is null. I have bound `this` to the call back function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things occuring here:

```
getTags.fetch(options).then(function(data){
      this.tags = data.tags //=> this.tags is a class level variable. data.tags = array of 5 objects.
    }, this);
```

Because JavaScript is asynchronous, anything before or after this will execute before you the request is returned. Once the request is returned, the promise will be fulfilled, however `console.log` will have already occurred.

There is also a context switch in your promise callback - which means `this` no longer refers to what you think it does. Although you say it is bound already, your function is anonymous so it is not. What I'm guessing though is that you want `this` to refer to the outter class. So to fix it, make your code something like:

```
var _this = this; // maintain a reference to your class instance
getTags.fetch(options).then(function(data){
    _this.tags = data.tags;
    console.log(_this.tags)
    // do your rendering
}, this);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you change your AJAX options to be synchronous by the time it calls console.log(this.tags), this.tags may not yet be set. You can try moving this log statement and the createPost inside of the promise callback like below.

```
create: function() { 
    $('#blog-manage').empty();
    var options = {reset: true};
    var getTags = new AisisWriter.Collections.Tags({per: 9999});

    getTags.fetch(options).then(function(data){
      this.tags = data.tags;  

      // move this logic inside the promise callback or put in a function
      // to call when callback has completed 
      console.log(this.tags) //=> null 
      var createPost = new AisisWriter.Views.CreatePost({tags: this.tags });
      createPost.render();
    }, this); 
},
```

As an edit to my first response I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottluskcis/5bqSU/) showing how you can handle this without chaining the promises together and getting "messy". This can be handled at the view level itself. You allow the view to handle what to do with the promise. This allow you to separate out the view logic and allow it to handle what to do when its model/collection changes, i.e. re-render itself. Below is some of the JavaScript from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottluskcis/5bqSU/), check it out to see full JavaScript and HTML.

```
AisisWriter.Views.CreatePost = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#tags-template").html()),

    el: "#blog-manage", 

    initialize: function () {
        // anytime our collection changes re-render view 
        // you can also use promise callback to call render
        // OPTION 1 
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "remove", this.render);

        // make the AJAX call to fetch items in our collection 
        // since backbone loads the collection for us we don't 
        // need the promise to assign data  
        // but you could attach the promise here
        // but is completely optional 
        this.collection.fetch(this.options.ajaxOptions)
            .then(_.bind(this.onFetchComplete, this)); // promise is optional    
        // OPTION 2 
        // .then(_bind(this.render, this)); // alternative

    },

    render: function () { 

        // wrap with tags to match how was in stack overflow post 
        var data = {
            tags: this.collection.toJSON()
        };

        this.$el.html(this.template(data));

        return this;
    },

    onFetchComplete: function (data) {
        // .. do something with data...
        // this is not needed though since Backbone
        // will have placed data in collection 
        // this is only here to show you can do something else
        // with the callback if you so desire 

        console.log('fetch of async data complete');

        // sample data just for demo
        // Backbone will have already populated the object 
        // you will notice b/c we used /echo/json as URL
        // of collection it added an empty object
        // since that is what jsfiddle sent back 
        this.collection.add([{
            title: 'foo',
            text: 'text of the post goes here'
        }, {
            title: 'bar',
            text: 'text of this post goes here'
        }]);

        // alternatively you could call render manually
        // instead of using listenTo in initialize method 
        // OPTION 3 
        // this.render(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: also, check the scope of this inside the create function itself. Depending on where you call the create method from and its scope is what 'this' will refer to. Either way the way you have the code in your example the then promise is asynchronous and will be called after so at the time you are trying to call this.tags, it has not yet been set by callback being resolved.

Comment: the problem with this is that if I want to also say, not go get my all the categories, so same concept as tags but for categories, would I do nested fetch calls? so `getTags.fetch().then(function(){ getCategories.fetch().then(function(){})})` like this just becomes a mess ....

Comment: If your view depends in the data you probably want to put subscribe to change even to to collection itself. On change of the collection render the view. I'll put together a js fiddle.

Comment: I've edited my original response with a jsfiddle example and some code regarding this.